# How to save path to executable that includes space and argument as variable?

Tags: bash

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /bin/bash

run="/Applications/YubiKey\ Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman openpgp"

$run info

$ ./test.sh: line 5: /Applications/YubiKey\: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to handle space in path to executable (`/Applications/YubiKey\ Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman`) and space between path and argument (`…/ykman openpgp`)?

Comment: The problem isn't the _storing_, the problem is the _using_. You're storing your string just fine, but `code='command "with quotes" and spaces'; $code` is not the same as `command "with quotes" and spaces`.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: BTW, while there are doubtless "answers" on the linked duplicate that suggest `eval`, _do not_ use `eval`; see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describing why. Either an array or a function is the right thing (BashFAQ #50 describes when to prefer either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the quotes *or* the backslash, not both.

```
run="/Applications/YubiKey Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman openpgp"
```

or

```
run=/Applications/YubiKey\ Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman \openpgp
```

---

Update: as this is a command name and an argument, not a single path name, you should be using either an array:

```
run=("/Applications/YubiKey Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman" openpgp)
"${run[@]}" info
```

or better yet, define a function instead of a variable:

```
run () {
    "/Applications/YubiKey Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/ykman" openpgp "$1"
}

run info
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I tried that second option and I get `test.sh: line 5: /Applications/YubiKey: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Somehow, this problem is harder to solve than it looks…

Comment: What's difficult? Spaces separate words unless escaped; `foo=bar baz` is two words, `foo=bar` and `baz`, while `foo=bar\ baz` is one single word containing a space. Quotes just escape every contained character, rather than requiring a backslash for every character. `foo="bar"` is effectively the same as `foo=\b\a\r`; most escaped characters simply retain their unescaped meaning.

Comment: `foo="bar\ baz"`, after quote removal, is a single word that contains a backslash *and* a space, because the quotes escape both the characters.

Comment: How do one handle space between “YubiKey” and “Manager” (which is a space in filename) vs space between “ykman” “openpgp” (which is a space between executable path and argument)?

Comment: Oh, that's an entirely separate problem. See update.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Btw, tried using a function, but that approach doesn’t work when arguments use quotes (for example: `$run foo bar "hello world"`.

Comment: Btw, would you happen to know whey question was closed?

Comment: That's because I used `"$1"`, not `"$@"`, in the definition, as you hadn't indicated that `run` could take some arbitrary number of arguments. The question was closed because this is substantially similar to the linked question.

Comment: Using an array worked. Thanks!